# How do you read data from a ADODB stream in ASP as byte values?

Tags: asp-classic, ado, jscript

I have an ASP routine that gets a binary file's contents and writes it to a stream.  The intention is to read it from the stream and process it at the server.

So I have:

```
ResponseBody = SomeRequest (SomeURL) ;

var BinaryInputStream = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Stream") ;
BinaryInputStream.Type = 1 ; // binary
BinaryInputStream.Open ;
BinaryInputStream.Write (ResponseBody) ;
BinaryInputStream.Position = 0 ;

var DataByte = BinaryInputStream.Read (1) ;

Response.Write (typeof (DataByte)) ; // displays "unknown"
```

How do I get the byte value of the byte I have just read from the stream?

Asc () and byte () don't work (JScript)

TIA

Comment: yup, classic asp, writing in JScript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I asked this question again in desperation and solved the problem.  See [Getting access to a binary response byte-by-byte in classic asp/JScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772123/getting-access-to-a-binary-response-byte-by-byte-in-classic-asp-jscript)